# Not able to get the string after a particular srting using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the strings which are after a particular string after reading a file. Here is my code.

```
while(! feof($file)) {

        $line_of_text = fgets($file);
        $msgIds[] = "";
        // Strict string match          
        $msgIdFound = preg_match('/#: [Section]/',$line_of_text);
        if($msgIdFound == 1){
            $parts = explode('#: [Section]', $line_of_text);
            echo $parts[0]."<br>";
            $counter++;

        }

}
```

The file consists of lines like

```
#: [Section]FacebookReturnButton
msgctxt "[Section]FacebookReturnButton"
msgid "Close This Window"
msgstr "Fermez cette fenêtre"

#: [Section]FixedShipping
msgctxt "[Section]FixedShipping"
msgid "Fixed Shipping"
msgstr "Frais de port fixe"
```

It has to get the strings after #: [Section] string (FacebookReturnButton,FixedShipping). Did I miss anything in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape `[`and`]` in regex. `[Section]` in regex means match a character in the list of `Section`.

```
$msgIdFound = preg_match('/#: \[Section\]/',$line_of_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your raw string haven't space after the "[Section]".
i think u should write:

```
$parts = explode('[Section]', $line_of_text);
```

Comment: Yeah. I found that. I've changed the code. I want the string exactly after #: [Section]..